# Dot Net Core MVC: How to Make a Query from a View?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a table with each record having a ParentId. I need to make a query from my index view to show the name of the Parent record instead of its Id. But I don't know how to use _context from view or how to handle the situation. Currently I can just see the Parent Id as it's in the model itself.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CollectionName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentId) // I need this to be _context.Groups.FirstOrDefault(m=>m.id == item.ParentId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CollectionHead)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: To do exactly what you're asking, you would need to pass the _context to the view. However, this is considered a bad practice as it tightly couples your view to acquisition of data. The view should only be displaying information. I suggest you research the concept of view models in mvc. Essentially, the view model contains the data formatted exactly for the view. The controller method would set the viewmodel up and pass it to the view. It is pretty rare to expose a model directly to a view. try: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managing-data-with-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: you want to make a query from your view? what does that mean?

Comment: @AndyStagg I see the point and I know the concepts, but the way I was thinking took me where I had no other choice but practicing the wrong way! Thank you for your nice answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be passing in a `Context` or any database logic to the views.

Your ViewModel should contain all the necessary data you need to display. It looks like in your ViewModel you are passing through a `ParentId` but this is really needed in the View. So you could change this to the actual `Parent` model or add another field into the ViewModel called `ParentName`. Then you'd be able to do something like this in the View, depending which suggestion you go for:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Parent.Name)
```

or

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentName)
```

Without looking at your Controller code it is quite hard to help on how to populate the ViewModel like this. But if your LINQ is correct then you can do this:

```
viewModel.Parent = _context.Groups.FirstOrDefault(m=>m.id == item.ParentId);
```

or

```
viewModel.ParentName = _context.Groups.FirstOrDefault(m=>m.id == item.ParentId).Name;
```

Comment: I appreciate your nice answer. The solution you provided is for a scenario where you have only one record. But in a table of records, ParentId changes for each record and I don't know how to update ParentId for each record. This table is my Index page where each record's parent id is different. How can I assign them in the controller and pass them to the view?

Comment: Then in your ViewModel you can pass through a `List` of `Parent`s. Then in your loop you can do `var parent in Model.ParentList`